# how to hide folder name from link

Tags: php, web

domain/pages/asd.php

I have a link in the form of I want to hide the pages folder. People need to write domain/asdf.php on the link and reach the file in the folder, how can I do it?

Comment: assuming you have [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) then a `rewrite` rule with your `.htaccess` file would work. [See here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/) for more

Comment: Can you provide sample code for htaccess?

Comment: [some examples](https://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod-rewrite-examples-2/) and [what StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-rewriting) has to say. There are plenty of examples out there... Rather than simply get given a specific answer you should try to learn the basics of this tech as it is very, very useful

Comment: What is the difference between `asd.php` and `asdf.php`?

Comment: Can you just move your php files up to the parent directory and delete the empty "pages" directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^pages/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) /pages/$1 [END]
```

This will ensure users can only access the url by the new route only (`/asd.php`) and not via both (I.e `/asd.php` & `/pages/asd.php`).

[View rewrite output](https://technicalseo.com/tools/htaccess/?share=ewogICJodGFjY2VzcyI6ICJSZXdyaXRlRW5naW5lIG9uXG5SZXdyaXRlUnVsZSBecGFnZXMvKC4rKSQgLyQxIFtSPTMwMSxMXVxuUmV3cml0ZUNvbmQgJXtSRVFVRVNUX0ZJTEVOQU1FfSAhLWZcblJld3JpdGVDb25kICV7UkVRVUVTVF9GSUxFTkFNRX0gIS1kXG5SZXdyaXRlUnVsZSAoLispIC9wYWdlcy8kMSBbRU5EXSIsCiAgInVybCI6ICJodHRwczovL2V4YW1wbGUuY29tL3BhZ2VzL2FzZC5waHAiCn0=)